# bash redirection get err: bad file descriptor and file still open, why?

Tags: linux, bash

when I run a simple cmd in bash, I got:

```
$echo 12312> aaa.txt
-bash: 12312: Bad file descriptor
$lsof aaa.txt
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
bash    20647 root    4r   REG    8,1        0 1409118 aaa.txt
$bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
$uname -a
Linux node39 3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Apr 20 16:44:24 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

is a bug here? I'm not familiar with the bash source code, but I want to
know why. So please give me some tips,best wish to you.

edit:
thx to answer my question, but I really want to know why aaa.txt still opened by
bash after error happend.

Comment: Use `double quotes`: `$ echo "12312"> aaa.txt`

Comment: Cannot reproduce. In any case, even had the redirection succeeded, the file wouldn't be kept open after the command terminated, so for all we know, that file is kept open by some other bash process.

Answer (score 2):

`spaces` - bash is very specific about spaces

```
echo 1234 > output.txt
```

int the above example `1234` in written to `output.txt` using redirection operator `>`

on the other hand if you omit the spaces

```
echo 1234> output.txt
```

redirection operator will treat `1234` as `"file descriptor number"`